# How to get Kafka brokers in a cluster using Spring Boot Kafka?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Spring Boot (2.3.3) service using spring-kafka to currently access a dedicated Kafka/Zookeeper configuration. I have been using the application.properties setting spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092 to access my dev/test Apache Kafka service.

However, in production, we have a Cluster of Kafka Brokers (on many servers) configured in Zookeeper, and I have been asked to modify my service to query Zookeeper to get the list of brokers and use that list instead of the bootstrap servers configuration. Reason, our DevOps folks have been known to reconfigure servers/nodes and Kafka brokers.

Basically, I have been asked to make my service agnostic to where the Apache Kafka brokers are running. All my service needs to know is how to get the list of brokers (bootstrap server info including host and port) from Zookeeper.

Is there a way in spring-boot and spring-kafka to retrieve from Zookeeper the broker list and use that broker (aka bootstrap server) list in my service?

Answer (score 3):

Spring delegates to the `kafka-clients` for all connections; for a long time now, the kafka-clients no longer connect to Zookeeper, only to the brokers themselves.

There is no built-in support in Spring for querying the Zookeeper to determine the broker list.

Furthermore, in a future Kafka version, Zookeeper is going away altogether; see [KIP-500](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-500%3A+Replace+ZooKeeper+with+a+Self-Managed+Metadata+Quorum).